# Node.js posting a large request using request module hangs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, post, request

I am using the node.js request module to post a large POST request (~150MB) to a REST service. For any request bigger than about 30MB, it seems to hang. My guess is that it is doing some naive `JSON.stringify()`ing to the data instead of streaming it, and once it gets large enough to hit swap, it just becomes very slow.

This is what my request looks like:

```
request({
  uri: url
  method: 'post',
  json: args, // args is a 150MB json object
}, function(err, resp, body) {
  // do something
});
```

The same request made using angularjs's $http from within a browser works in less than a minute, so I know it's the cilent and not the server.

Is there an easy way to fix this?

Comment: Hi, were you able to find a solution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

Updating answer:

I'd suggest your try two things :

1. See how much time superagent is taking to post the same data. Superagent is as simple as request.

   ```
   var request = require('superagent');
    request
     .post(url)
     .send(args)
     .set('Accept', 'application/json')
     .end(function(error, res){

   });
   ```
2. Compress the data to be posted by using zlip, your will be compressing the data into a zlip buffer and write that as your output

   ```
   var zlib = require('zlib');
   var options = {
    hostname: 'www.yourwebsite.com',
    port: 80,
    path: '/your-post-url',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {'Content-Encoding': 'gzip'} // tell the server that the data is compressed
   };

   //args is your JSON stringified data

    zlib.gzip(args, function (err, buffer) {

    var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
    res.setEncoding('utf8');
    res.on('data', function (chunk) {
           // ... do stuff with returned data
    });
   });

   req.on('error', function(e) {
       console.log('problem with request: ' + e.message);
   });

   req.write(buffer); // send compressed data

   req.end();

   });
   ```

Comment: Sorry, I realized my question wasn't clear enough (updated question to show example). The issue is that the *request* is large, not the response. I am using request, not superagent.

Comment: I just updated my answer to suggest compressing the post data and secondly if you could compare the time taken by superagent to post the data that would be great

Answer (score 0):

Streaming is not going to happen automatically. The API to stream something and the API to send a complete buffer are almost always different, and this is no exception. Most libraries out there given a complete javascript object in memory are just going to `JSON.stringify` it because you've already paid the memory and I/O price to load it in RAM so why bother streaming?

You could try the [oboe streaming JSON library](http://oboejs.com/api), which specializes in this type of thing. Here's a working example:

```
var oboe = require("oboe");
var args = {foo: "bar"};
var url = "http://localhost:2998";

oboe({url: url, body: args, method: "post"}).on("done", function (response) {
  console.log('response:', response);
});
```

---

Aside: instead of guessing, you could [verify in the source](https://github.com/request/request/blob/f0acc0b3e0bbc8a57d3418ab93eadbf162089514/request.js#L1439) exactly what is happening. It's open source. It's javascript. Go ahead and dig in!

Comment: It sounds like a common enough problem, that surely there's an off-the-shelf solution somewhere?

Aside: It seemed fairly obvious based on the symptoms. I have now checked, and they do indeed use JSON.stringify.

Comment: By the way, the interface I'm looking for is exactly the same: `request(args, callback)`. I just want it to stream under the hood when args is large.

Comment: Appreciate the edit, but unfortunately, oboe also `JSON.stringify()`es the request. The reason you would stream is there is a significant memory overhead to performing the stringification. A JSON string can be many times larger than the object's in-memory representation.

https://github.com/jimhigson/oboe.js/blob/5472c8dacd21ba3fd1c604f7314402505ff7bf82/src/defaults.js#L15

Comment: I'm intrigued what alternatives to JSON.stringify there are and would for sure build these into Oboe if there is one already out there (at least for while running under Node and possibly also in the browser). Do you know of a write-to-stream version of JSON.stringify in npm?